# Question about aircraft/rockets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Lets say that you're sitting an inverted airplane. How do you determine how fast the plane must accelerate in order for you to not fall out?

Comment: If you've even flown you know that if you drop an apple it falls to the floor just as it does on the ground. So if the pilot is flying inverted and level, then she would fall out of her seat if she is not strapped in.

Comment: But at some point, isn't there a velocity that the aircraft would push you?

Comment: You'd have to be accelerating for the plane to push the pilot into the seat. If the plane is at a constant velocity then gravity would be the only applicable force.

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on two things: The coefficient of friction between the pilot and his seat and the direction of acceleration.

First case: The aircraft accelerates along its flight path. The pilot is pressed against the seat by the acceleration, and if that pressure is sufficient, friction will keep him in place. Since the coefficient of static friction $\mu_s$ is equivalent to the tangent of the [inner frictional angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction), and the ratio between gravity and acceleration is also a tangent, the acceleration $a$ along the flight path must be
$$a > g\cdot \mu_s$$ 
assuming a horizontal flight path and a vertical backrest. For different flight path and backrest angles correct accordingly.

Second case: The aircraft flies a parabola such that the pilot is pressed into his seat by centrifugal forces. If the angular velocity of the pitch motion is $q$ and the centrifugal force has to be greater than the pilot's weight, the condition is
$$q > \frac{g}{v}$$
The higher the speed $v$ you accelerate to is, the smaller the minimum pitch rate becomes.

Answer (score 0):

The plane should travel with such an acceleration so that the weight of the force of the plane should be greater than the weight of the plane. Higher the force , the more the pilot pushed towards the seat.